# Pass Hash from URL to a Function with Delay

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pass a has such as http://mysite.com/#32132 via JS to a custom function.

Here's the function:

```
var downloadVideo = function(passed){
  console.log(passed);
}
```

And here's how I'm getting and passing the hash from the URL:

```
if(window.location.hash){
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    hash = hash.substring(1, hash.length); // Remove the # from the hash
    setTimeout('downloadVideo('+hash+')', 3000)
}
```

After 3 seconds, I just get an error in the console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: 32132 is not defined

I've tried different ways of calling downloadVideo. With quotes, without quotes, without the plus signs. Nothing seems to work. If I console.log the hash var immediately before the setTimeout it displays it correctly.

Comment: I copied and pasted your scripts into a new page and I'm not getting an error, so there's some information you're not giving us.  32132 will work because it's a number, but is it not a number that you're passing?  It seems like it thinks 32132 is a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to represent it as a string if there's anything more than just numeric characters...

```
     // ------------------v--------v
setTimeout('downloadVideo("'+hash+'")', 3000);
```

---

But better to pass a function that closes over `hash`...

```
setTimeout(function() { downloadVideo(hash) }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a closure to do that:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  downloadVideo(hash);
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You don't need the second argument in your has substring - if omitted, the substring matches to the end of the string

2) with timeouts it's better to use anonymous functions; evaluated strings are, well, evaluated. Generally a bad idea.

3) the error is coming because you're passing a string without quotes. Fixing point 2 to use an anonymous function would make this error both more visible and harder to commit in the first place

4) you could always apply the timeout in the function, rather than in the call to it

Anyway:

```
setTimeout(function() { downloadVideo(hash); }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the value of `hash` is `test` then:

```
'downloadVideo('+hash+')'
```

...evaluates to:

```
downloadVideo(test)
```

Notice that there are no quotes around the string `test` so it's treated as though it refers to a variable (that doesn't exist). This is one of many reasons not to pass strings to `setTimeout`. It's a bad practice, as described here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don%27t_use_eval!

It's far better to pass a function to `setTimeout`. **It's safer, easier to read, and doesn't suffer from the problem you've see here.** When no arguments are required, simply refer to the function by name:

```
setTimeout(downloadVideo, 3000)
```

If arguments are required, as they are in your case, then you'll need to pass a reference to an anonymous function and have that function call the function that you want to invoke:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    downloadVideo(hash);
}, 3000)
```